# How to add and remove classes from dynamically created elements in Angular 2+ (no ngClass)?

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I am dynamically creating a list of elements on a page in Angular 6. Each item on the list has a button on the right that, when clicked, opens a dropdown menu with a delete option. Because it's a dropdown, I need to hide/show it when it's clicked on. I'm not sure what the best practice is for doing so in Angular.

I don't think I can use ngClass, as these are dynamically created, and if I had `dropdownIsToggled: boolean = false` because it would open every dropdown instead of the specific one that was clicked. I am still somewhat inexperienced with Angular and I want to know what the best practice would be in this situation.

So far I have this html inside an ngFor

```html
<span class="item-dropdown">
    <button class="item-dropdown-button" (click)="toggleDropdown()">
        <i class="bicon bicon-more-vertical bicon-md"></i>
    </button>
    <div *ngIf="dropdownIsToggled" class="item-dropdown-menu shadow-md">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <button class="list-item"
                (click)="deleteItem(item.id)">
                    delete
                </button>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button class="list-item" (click)="markRead(item.id)">
                    mark as read
                </button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</span>
```

And here is my non-working toggle function (as it toggles every dropdown in the list when clicked) in the component

```
dropdownIsToggled: boolean = false;
toggleDropdown() {
    this.dropdownIsToggled = !this.dropdownIsToggled;
}
```

My immediate idea is to set each item to have an id of the index of the loop `*ngFor="let item of items; let i = index"`, pass the index through the toggleDropdown function, and then add/remove classes to hide/show the dropdown in that way, but I am not sure of best practices in this situation, and I would like input. Is it going against best practice to change css classes from the component?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to add the `dropdownIsToggled` to the `item`model.

Like

```
interface Item {
   id: any,
   dropdownIsToggled: boolean,
   ... other props
}
```

In your html you do something like

```
<span class="item-dropdown">
<button class="item-dropdown-button" (click)="toggleDropdown(item)">
    <i class="bicon bicon-more-vertical bicon-md"></i>
</button>
<div *ngIf="item.dropdownIsToggled" class="item-dropdown-menu shadow-md">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <button class="list-item"
            (click)="deleteItem(item.id)">
                delete
            </button>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button class="list-item" (click)="markRead(item.id)">
                mark as read
            </button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

TS:

```
toggleDropdown(item) {
   item.dropdownIsToggled = !item.dropdownIsToggled;
}
```

If you don't want to add UI specific properties to your model, you can do something like this:

```
interface Item {
   id: any,
   ... other props
}
interface ItemUI extends Item {
   dropdownIsToggled: boolean,
}
```

In this way you can provide a clean state for every item.